# How do I get a workflow to run the HttpListener?

Tags: web-services, httplistener

DESCRIPTION

I'm using

- SharePoint Designer 2013
- SharePoint 2019
- Windows Server 2019

I found some code called HttpListener that is written in PowerShell.
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/HttpListener/1.0.2/Content/HTTPListener.psm1

After I started the HttpListener function in the code I opened a browser to run the web service manually.
Example: http://localhost:8888/PowerShell?command=Jane.Doe&format=text
As advertised, it created an active directory account.  That is what I need it to do.

PROBLEM

The problem is I'm not able to get a SharePoint workflow for a list to do the same thing as running the web service in a browser window.

WHAT I TRIED

1. I create a workflow for a list.
2. In the workflow I created a single step where the only action is "Call HTTP Web Service".
3. The values for the "Call HTTP Web Service" are as follows: (NOTE: I'm only sending data to the web service.  I don't need anything back.  If it sends something back, then that is fine.  But, I don't need it.)
   3.1. this = http://localhost:8888/PowerShell?command=John.Smith&format=text (Method = HTTP POST)
   3.2. request = left empty
   3.3. response = left empty
   3.4. responseHeader = left empty
   3.5. Variable: responseCode = left empty

Transition to Stage = End of Workflow.

I made sure the user account running the workflow in SharePoint had the same rights as the account running the web service in the browser.

WHAT WAS I EXPECTING

I was expecting the web service to work in the SharePoint workflow just like it did when I used the browser.

Any suggestions or alternatives?